# Background gradients for IE: is #RRGGBB format required?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, linear-gradients

I've found a lot of sites that explain that an IE gradient should be made using:

```
.IEGradient {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#AAAAAA', endColorstr='#BBBBBB');
}
```

but since I would need to be able to accept the direct input of colours by users, I'd like to know if these `*Colorstr`s are limited to just the `#RRGGBB` format, or if other formats such as `#RGB` or `rgb(r, g, b)` etc. would also work. I've tried googling for answers, but I couldn't find any site saying the long HEX format was required, but I just kept finding more and more sites that all just used the long hex format, and none that used any other formats, so that made me wonder.

By the way, msdn says [`#AARRGGBB` format is required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), yet there are enough sites that don't include the `AA` part, so that still makes me wonder if other formats would work, if the format that isn't mentioned on msdn also works.

Comment: Why not test with other color formats in the code snippet you already got there?

Comment: @Ken because I don't have an old version of IE on my computer. Also, I don't want to downgrade the version of IE I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the emulation tab in IE11's dev tools, and apparently you can emulate down to IE5 there. It turns out that indeed only the `#AARRGGBB` and `#RRGGBB` formats are allowed. Any other format causes it to render a blue-to-black gradient.

Comment: Glad the emulation options were helpful. That's why they're there. Please be careful about relying on them too much though: they are **not** 100% accurate compared with real copies of older IE versions; there are some fairly significant differences that will catch you out if you use it to test without also testing in real copies of each IE version. Other options you might want to try include using a VM to run each IE version for real (MS provide these for free; see http://modern.ie/) or a remote testing service like http://browsershots.org/ or http://browserstack.com/.