# CSS Creating Opacity Gradient

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a class to apply to elements which will give them a gradient using CSS. The problem is that I want a class that contains NO COLOR- only opacity from 1.0 to 0. This way, I can "lay" it down on top of any element with any color and it will give it a gradient, basically starting with the original color and fading to white.

```
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e9e9e9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e9e9e9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e9e9e9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

How do I do this without specifying any color?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kst95/?

Comment: @j08691 Out of curiosity, do you need the `0%` if the color chosen is `transparent`?

Comment: @davidpauljunior - The 0% is the position so I believe so.

Comment: @j08691 aha, thanks for clearing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without specifying the colour to transition into. What you could do is use `rgba()` to define a color and then also its opacity, but only affecting the opacity itself is not possible. An example of a gradient you'd get when using `rgba()` would be:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 233, 233, 0) 100%); /* W3C */
```

that would transition between the two specified colours, going from completely transparent at the `#e9e9e9` (which is the same as `rgba(233, 233, 233, 1)`) to completely opaque at the white. Again, this is an alternative to what you actually want, but transitioning opacity only is not possible.

PS: you can also transition translucent colours in older IE versions using [`#AARRGGBB` format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20993511/1256925).